# Spring - Update OneToMany collection from web-form

Tags: spring, jpa

I'm trying to delete one of the values in the form.

```
public class Parameter {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "param_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "param_name")
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "param_id", referencedColumnName = "param_id")
    private List<ParamValue> values;
}
```

and

```
public class ParamValue {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "value_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "value_name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="param_id")
    private Parameter parameter;
}
```

form:

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="parameter">
    <form:input path="name" />

    <c:forEach items="${parameter.values}" var="paramValue" varStatus="uStatus">
        <div>
            <form:input path="values[${uStatus.index}].id" type="hidden"/>
            <form:input path="values[${uStatus.index}].name" type="text" />
            <form:input path="values[${uStatus.index}].parameter" type="hidden" />
            <button type="button" onclick="$(this).parent().remove();">x</button>
        </div>
    </c:forEach>

    <input type="submit" value="save" class="btn btn-success">
</form:form>
```

In my db exists next values:

in Param:

```
------------------
| id | name      |
------------------
| 3  | TestParam |
------------------
```

in ParamValue:

```
-----------------------------
| id  | name    | parameter |
-----------------------------
| 116 | value 1 | 3         |
-----------------------------
| 117 | value 2 | 3         |
-----------------------------
| 119 | value 3 | 3         |
-----------------------------
| 152 | value 4 | 3         |
-----------------------------
```

and controller:

```
@Controller(value = "ParamsSave")
@RequestMapping("/params/save")
public class Save extends Base {
    @Autowired
    private ParamRepo paramRepo;

    @ModelAttribute("parameter")
    public Parameter getParam(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) Long param_id) {
        if(param_id == null) {
            return new Parameter();
        }

        Parameter parameter = paramRepo.findById(param_id);
        return parameter == null ? new Parameter() : parameter;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String get(Parameter parameter) {
        return getTemplate();
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String post(@Valid Parameter parameter, BindingResult result) {
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return getTemplate();
        }

        paramRepo.save(parameter);

        return "redirect: /";
    }
}
```

If i delete value "value 2", a get error:

> identifier of an instance of beans.ParamValue was altered from 117 to
>   119; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier
>   of an instance of beans.ParamValue was altered from 117 to 119

If i delete last value then nothing happens, there is no error and field not delete.

Why does this happen, how do I remove a value from the list?

Comment: Where is the delete code?

Answer (score 0):

I can see three problems in your code:

The first one is that the association mapping is wrong. In a bidirectional association, one side must be the *owning* side and the other one the *inverse* side. A correct mapping would be the following:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parameter", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<ParamValue> values;
```

and

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="param_id")
private Parameter parameter;
```

Note that I also dropped the `cascade=ALL` as it makes no sense in the context of `@ManyToOne` (you can't cascade deletion of a `ParameterValue` to its owning `Parameter` for instance, as other `ParameterValue`s would still reference it, leading to constraint violation exceptions).

That being said, I have serious doubts as to whether a bidirectional association is needed at all. Why not simply map `Parameter.values` as:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "param_id", referencedColumnName = "param_id")
private List<ParamValue> values;
```

and drop the `ParamValue.parameter` field altogether? Judging by the use case you've described, `ParamValues` are *privately owned* by `Parameter` anyway.

The other problem is that HTML form inputs can only be used with simple values. I'm not entirely sure what the following line does:

```
<form:input path="values[${uStatus.index}].parameter" type="hidden" />
```

Chances are, however, that it does not do what you expect. In any case, I would not rely on the `ParameterValue.parameter` field being set properly within the `Save.post` handler. If you choose to keep the `ParameterValue.parameter` field, you should iterate over the `Parameter.values` list, and set the field manually for each element.

Finally, using `$(this).parent().remove()` means that there will be a gap in the submitted `parameter.values[]` array (i.e. the index originally corresponding to the removed element will be missing), which is consistent with your observation that deleting the last value behaves differently. You should definitely inspect the contents of `Parameter.values` as received by `Save.post` using the debugger.